# Inverse rule to the L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

If in L'Hôpital's rule we have that: $f,g :(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$, there exist $f'(x)$, $g'(x)$, and $g'(x)\ne0$,

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L,$$

and also $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) = 0$, must it be also

$$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$$

or not? I think it is wrong in some cases, but I can't find an example.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin(x)$, $g(x)=x$, $a=\infty$.

Comment: I'm sorry, there is some additional conditions

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking.

Comment: We know that  L'Hôpital's rule is correct. Does correct that  L'Hôpital's rule works at back way?

Comment: I think the question does not at all reflect what Steel_Rat has in mind. I believe he wants to know whether $\lim f'/g' = \lim f/g$ when $\lim f'/g'$ has indeterminate form (short answer: no.)

Comment: Could someone tell me if the inverse L'Hôpital's rule works in the case that $f’(x)$ and $g’(x)$ are both monotonically increasing ?

Comment: @Angelo convexity is not enough for deducing $f'/g'$ from $f/g$. I guess you already proved that this implication works if one of the two functions is a polynomial (per your comment to a more recent question). But you cannot further generalize.

Comment: @dfnu, please, could you write a counterexample about the fact that convexity is not enough for deducing $f’/g’$ from $f/g\;?\;$ Actually I have already proved that this implication works if $\,g(x)=x^p\,$ where $\,p\in\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: @Angelo my example is really convoluted. I'm sure if you ask a question you'll get a much nicer answer from the rest of the community!

Comment: @dfnu, please tell me about your counterexample, no matter how convoluted it may seem.

Comment: @Angelo Too little time right now to type all the details. When you post a proper answer, if nobody gives you the example you require faster than me, I'll try to show you mine. In the meantime, I suggest you look into the details of your proof for monomials. You should see the main reason why the reverse of de l'Hopital works in this case and this may help you looking in the right direction for a more "pathological" situation.

Comment: @Angelo did you make any progress in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is that there may be a case that $\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$ does not exist.

So let's define

$$g(x)=x, \quad f(x)=\int_0^x(1+\sin(1/y))dy$$.

Apparently $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$, and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$ does not exist.

The tricky part is to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)/g(x)=1$. But first of all, it is true intuitively because $\sin(1/y)$ oscillates infinitely fast so the integral cancels out.

More rigorously, we can treat the integral by define $z=1/y$
$$
\int_0^x\sin(1/y)dy=\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz
$$

It can be shown that $\int_\alpha^\infty[\sin(z)/z^2]dz$ is bounded by two sums
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n>\int_\alpha^\infty\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz>\sum_{n=N}^\infty b_n
$$

Where $N\equiv \lfloor \alpha/(2\pi)\rfloor$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are defiend as 
$$
a_n\equiv \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz, \quad b_n\equiv \int_{(2n-1)\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz 
$$

$$
a_n=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin(z)\left(\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{(z+\pi)^2}\right)dz
$$
So 
$$
0<a_n<\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{(z+\pi)^2}\right)dz =\frac{2\pi^2}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)\pi^3}
$$
Thus $a_n\sim\mathcal{O}(1/n^3)$, and $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n \sim \mathcal{O}(1/N^2)=\mathcal{O}(1/\alpha^2)$

btw,the properties of the sum can be found on wolframalpha if you are interested.
[link 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5B1/n%5E3,%7Bn,N,%5Cinfty%7D%5D) [link 2](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/06/02/)

Similarly we can prove that $0>\sum_{n=N}^\infty b_n \sim \mathcal{O}(1/\alpha^2)$

So 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\sin(1/y)dy=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}dz =\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{ x}\mathcal{O}(x^2)=0
$$

Comment: Nice answer! I like it very much. Could you tell me if the inverse L'Hôpital's rule works in the case that $f’(x)$ and $g’(x)$ are both monotonically increasing ?